# Python: get all months in range?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get all months between now and August 2010, as a list formatted like this:

```
['2010-08-01', '2010-09-01', .... , '2016-02-01']
```

Right now this is what I have:

```
months = []
for y in range(2010, 2016):
    for m in range(1, 13):
        if (y == 2010) and m < 8:
            continue
        if (y == 2016) and m > 2:
            continue
        month = '%s-%s-01' % (y, ('0%s' % (m)) if m < 10 else m)
        months.append(month)
```

What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`dateutil.relativedelta`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relativedelta.html) is handy here.

I've left the  formatting out as an exercise.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

result = []

today = datetime.date.today()
current = datetime.date(2010, 8, 1)    

while current <= today:
    result.append(current)
    current += relativedelta(months=1)
```

Comment: Ani, this is nearly correct, but you have to format the datetime in a way that it appears in the ISO format. This can be done by appending the isoformat. You should change the line to `result.append(current.isoformat())` - [EDIT: didn't see that you left the formatting out as an exercise... but oh well.]

Comment: Thanks, I actually did `result.append(datetime.strftime(current, '%Y-%m-01'))` to get the format I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

I had a look at the `dateutil` documentation. Turns out it provides an even more convenient way than using `dateutil.relativedelta`: [recurrence rules](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rrule.html) ([examples](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#rrule-examples))

For the task at hand, it's as easy as

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
from datetime import date

months = map(
    date.isoformat,
    rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=date(2010, 8, 1), until=date.today())
)
```

## The fine print

Note that we're cheating a little bit, here. The elements `dateutil.rrule.rrule` produces are of type `datetime.datetime`, even if we pass `dtstart` and `until` of type `datetime.date`, as we do above. I let `map` feed them to `date`'s `isoformat` function, which just turns out to convert them to strings as if it were just dates without any time-of-day information.

Therefore, the seemingly equivalent list comprehension

```
[day.isoformat()
    for day in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=date(2010, 8, 1), until=date.today())]
```

would return a list like

```
['2010-08-01T00:00:00',
 '2010-09-01T00:00:00',
 '2010-10-01T00:00:00',
 '2010-11-01T00:00:00',
 ⋮
 '2015-12-01T00:00:00',
 '2016-01-01T00:00:00',
 '2016-02-01T00:00:00']
```

Thus, if we want to use a list comprehension instead of `map`, we have to do something like

```
[dt.date().isoformat()
    for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=date(2010, 8, 1), until=date.today())]
```

Comment: Note that the iteration variable `day` in the first list comprehension is a _deliberate_ misnomer. As explained, it holds a `datetime`, not a `date`.

Answer (score 9):

use `datetime` and `timedelta` standard Python's modules - without installing any new libraries

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime(datetime.now().year, datetime.now().month, 1)
ctr = datetime(2010, 8, 1)
list = [ctr.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]

while ctr <= now:
    ctr += timedelta(days=32)
    list.append( datetime(ctr.year, ctr.month, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
```

I'm adding `32` days to enter new month every time (longest months has `31` days)

Comment: this is a nice solution, but you should add `ctr = ctr.replace(day=1)` after `ctr = timedelta(days=32)`, otherwise you'll to skip a month in a longer period. Look at this sequence: [2018-10-28, 2018-11-29, 2018-12-31, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-05] -> January has been skipped here. Setting day=1 avoids this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems like there's a very simple and clean way to do this by generating a list of dates and subsetting to take only the first day of each month, as shown in the example below.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime.date(2010,8,1)
end_date = datetime.date(2016,2,1)

date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
date_range = date_range[date_range.day==1]

print(date_range)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got another way using datetime, timedelta and calender:

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def monthdelta(d1, d2):
    delta = 0
    while True:
        mdays = monthrange(d1.year, d1.month)[1]
        d1 += timedelta(days=mdays)
        if d1 <= d2:
            delta += 1
        else:
            break
    return delta

start_date = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2016, 12, 1)

num_months = [i-12 if i>12 else i for i in range(start_date.month, monthdelta(start_date, end_date)+start_date.month+1)]
monthly_daterange = [datetime(start_date.year,i, start_date.day, start_date.hour) for i in num_months]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Mattaf, but simpler...
[pandas.date_range()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) has an option frequency freq='m'...
Here I am adding a day (`pd.Timedelta('1d')`) in order to reach the beginning of each new month:

```
import pandas as pd
date_range = pd.date_range('2010-07-01','2016-02-01',freq='M')+pd.Timedelta('1d')
print(list(date_range))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the number of `if` statements to two lines instead of four lines because having a second `if` statement that does the same thing with the previous `if` statement is a bit redundant.

```
if (y == 2010 and m < 8) or (y == 2016 and m > 2):
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's *better*, but an approach like the following might be considered more 'pythonic':

```
months = [
    '{}-{:0>2}-01'.format(year, month)
        for year in xrange(2010, 2016 + 1)
        for month in xrange(1, 12 + 1)
        if not (year <= 2010 and month < 8 or year >= 2016 and month > 2)
]
```

The main differences here are:

- As we want the iteration(s) to produce a list, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of aggregating list elements in a `for` loop.
- Instead of explicitly making a distinction between numbers below 10 and numbers 10 and above, use the capabilities of the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) for the [`.format()` method of `str`](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to specify

  - a [field width](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#grammar-token-width) (the `2` in the `{:0>2}` place holder)
  - right-[alignment within the field](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#grammar-token-align) (the `>` in the `{:0>2}` place holder)
  - zero-[padding](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#grammar-token-fill) (the `0` in the `{:0>2}` place holder)
- `xrange` instead of `range` returns a generator instead of a list, so that the iteration values can be produced as they're being consumed and don't have to be held in memory. (Doesn't matter for ranges this small, but it's a good idea to get used to this in Python 2.) **Note**: In Python 3, there is no `xrange` and the `range` function already returns a generator instead of a list.
- Make the `+ 1` for the upper bounds explicit. This makes it easier for human readers of the code to recognize that we want to specify an inclusive bound to a method (`range` or `xrange`) that treats the upper bound as exclusive. Otherwise, they might wonder what's the deal with the number 13.

Comment: Even more pythonic is of course using `dateutil` and `datetime` to deal with dates and time differences, as [Ani's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35651063/674064) does.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that **doesn't require any additional libraries, nor nested or while loops**. Simply convert your dates into an absolute number of months from some reference point (it can be any date really, but for simplicity we can use 1st January 0001). For example

```
a=datetime.date(2010,2,5)
abs_months = a.year * 12 + a.month
```

Once you have a number representing the month you are in you can simply use `range` to loop over the months, and then convert back:

**Solution to the generalized problem:**

```
import datetime

def range_of_months(start_date, end_date):
    months = []
    for i in range(start_date.year * 12 + start_date.month, end_date.year*12+end_date.month + 1)
        months.append(datetime.date((i-13) // 12 + 1, (i-1) % 12 + 1, 1))
    return months
```

**Additional Notes/explanation:**

Here `//` divides rounding down to the nearest whole number, and `% 12` gives the remainder when divided by 12, e.g. `13 % 12` is `1`.

(Note also that in the above `date.year *12 + date.month` does not give the number of months since the 1st of January 0001. For example if `date = datetime.datetime(1,1,1)`, then `date.year * 12 + date.month` gives `13`. If I wanted to do the actual number of months I would need to subtract 1 from the year and month, but that would just make the calculations more complicated. All that matters is that we have a consistent way to convert to and from some integer representation of what month we are in.)

Answer (score 0):

fresh pythonic one-liner from me

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime

[(start_date + relativedelta(months=+m)).isoformat() 
    for m in range(0, relativedelta(start_date, end_date).months+1)]
```

Comment: I believe you want start_date and end_date swapped in the relativedelta call

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have any months duplicates and they are in correct order you can get what you want with this.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

first = date.today()
last = first + timedelta(weeks=20)
date_format = "%Y-%m"

results = []

while last >= first:
    results.append(last.strftime(date_format))
    last -= timedelta(days=last.day)
```