# How to get the number of Days in a Specific Month between Two Dates in Python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, odoo-10, odoo-accounting

I have two date fields `campaign_start_date` and `campaign_end_date`. I want to count the number of days in each month that comes in-between the `campaign_start_date` and `campaign_end_date`.

eg:

```
campaign_start_date  = September 7 2017
campaign_end_date    = November 6 2017
```

The solution should be :

```
Total No:of days       = 61 days
No: of months          = 3 months
Month 1                = 9/7/2017 to 9/30/2017
Month 2                = 10/1/2017 to 10/31/2017
Month 3                = 11/1/2017 to 11/6/2017
No:of days in Month 1  = 24 days
No:of days in Month 2  = 31 days
No:of days in Month 3  = 6 days
```

How can I achieve this using Python?
So far I have achieved:

```
@api.multi
    def print_date(self):
        start_date = datetime.strptime(self.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(self.end_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        campaign_start_date = date(start_date.year,start_date.month,start_date.day)
        campaign_end_date = date(end_date.year,end_date.month,end_date.day)
        duration = (campaign_end_date-campaign_start_date).days  
        return True
```

Comment: I got the total number of days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculate the duration in days:

```
from datetime import date

campaign_start_date = date(2017, 9, 7)
campaign_end_date = date(2017, 10, 6)
duration = (campaign_end_date-campaign_start_date).days
print campaign_start_date, campaign_end_date, duration
```

Some hints for further calculations:

```
import calendar

campaign_end_month_start = campaign_end_date.replace(day=1)
days_in_month_campaign_end = (campaign_end_date - campaign_end_month_start).days + 1

range_startmonth = calendar.monthrange(campaign_start_date.year, campaign_start_date.month)
campaign_start_month_ends = campaign_start_date.replace(day=range_startmonth[1])

days_in_month_campaign_begins = (campaign_start_month_ends - campaign_start_date).days
```

This way you can calculate the number of days in each month of the campaign (keep in mind to check if `campaign_end_date` is in another month than `campaign_start_date`

For calculations you can also access the fields of a date, e.g.

```
campaign_start_date.day
campaign_start_date.month
campaign_start_date.year
```

To calculate the number of involved month in your campaign and to get a list of the month to calculate the duration per month you can use this (based on the answer of m.antkowicz in [Python: get all months in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650793/python-get-all-months-in-range)). It's important to set the day to 1 (`current = current.replace(day=1)`) before and inside the loop, otherwise you skip a month when your startdate is 31st of a month and the next month is shorter than 31 days or if you have a longer period:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta    
current = campaign_start_date
result = [current]

current = current.replace(day=1)
while current <= campaign_end_date:
    current += timedelta(days=32)
    current = current.replace(day=1)
    result.append(datetime(current.year, current.month, 1))

print result, len(result)
```

which prints (when you use `current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`:

> ['2017-09-07', '2017-10-01', '2017-11-01'] 3

now you can loop over the result list and calculate the number of days per months:

```
durations= []
for curr in result:
    curr_range = calendar.monthrange(curr.year, curr.month)
    curr_duration = (curr_range[1] - curr.day)+1
    if (curr.month < campaign_end_date.month):
        durations.append(curr_duration)
    else:
        durations.append(campaign_end_date.day)

print durations
```

which gives you the desired "No:of days in Month x" as a list:

> [24, 31, 6]

Comment: Thankyou for taking time to answer my question, it was really helpful.

Comment: It works for dates in the same years. For dates from different years, it gives the wrong result in "durations". Also, it provides one extra month after end_date. Added the one single method which is robust to all dates

Answer (score 1):

This is the robust solution which takes care of dates from different years.

```
def get_months_and_durations(start_date,end_date):
    current = start_date
    result = [current]

    current = current.replace(day=1)
    while current <= end_date:
        current += timedelta(days=32)
        current = current.replace(day=1)
        result.append(datetime(current.year, current.month, 1).date())

    durations= []
    for curr in result[:-1]:
        curr_range = calendar.monthrange(curr.year, curr.month)
        curr_duration = (curr_range[1] - curr.day)+1

        if ((curr.month == end_date.month) & (curr.year == end_date.year)):
            durations.append(end_date.day)
        else:
            durations.append(curr_duration)
    return result[:-1],durations
```