# Python function for getting a list of the past X months

Tags: python, django

Trying to make a template tag for my Django blog archive to show the last four months of the year, ie:

```
<a>October 2017</a>
<a>September 2017</a>
<a>August 2017</a>
<a>July 2017</a>
```

I'm certain that it's so simple it's stupid but I'm just not getting it! Here's what I've got so far:

```
@register.simple_tag
def last_four_months(format):
    today = datetime.today()
    four_months = today - relativedelta(months=4)
    for month in four_months:
    return four_months.strftime(format)
```

This throws a `TypeError - 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable`

Comment: `[today - relativedelta(months=i) for i in range(4)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it manually for last four months of the year

```
today = datetime.today()
months = [today.replace(month=m).strftime(format) for m in range(9,13)]
```

Returns

```
['September 2017', 'October 2017', 'November 2017', 'December 2017']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider dateutil.rrule

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
from datetime import date

months = map(
    date.isoformat,
    rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=four_months, until=today)
)
```

Better approaches you may find here [Python: get all months in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650793/python-get-all-months-in-range)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method...

```
`import datetime
def get_past_months(previos_month_count):
    month_list=[]
    today = datetime.date.today()
    first = today.replace(day=1)
    last_month = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    month_list.append(last_month.strftime("%Y-%m"))
    for i in range(1, previos_month_count):
        first = last_month.replace(day=1)
        last_month = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        month_list.append(last_month.strftime("%Y-%m"))
    return month_list`
```